# Using the subsetting operator :: in quantmod with variables

Tags: r, subset, quantmod

How do I apply a user initialized date variables as the start and end values of the subset operator `::` from the R-package, quantmod?

For example, when I apply user initialized date variables,

```
end.date        <- Sys.Date()
start.date      <- end.date - 5*365 #5- years to-date
start.date.char <- as.character(start.date)
end.date.char   <- as.character(end.date)
```

to get 5-years of stock data

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GILD",src="yahoo")
GILD.5YTD <- GILD['start.date.char::end.date.char']
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in if (length(c(year, month, day, hour, min, sec))
   == 6 && c(year,  :
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

In addition: Warning messages:

```
1: In as_numeric(YYYY) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as_numeric(MM) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In as_numeric(DD) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In as_numeric(YYYY) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In as_numeric(MM) : NAs introduced by coercion
6: In as_numeric(DD) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I'm a newbie.

Comment: Reading `?"[.xts"`, you could probably be looking for `GILD[paste(start.date.char, end.date.char, sep = "/")]`?

Comment: This does the job. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are convenient high-level functions to subset an xts object as returned, e.g., by quantmod's `getSymbols()`.

For a time-based subset, the `last()` function from the xts package (automatically loaded by quantmod) is quite handy:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GILD",src="yahoo")
GILD_last5Years <- last(GILD, "5 years")
#> head(GILD_last5Years)
#           GILD.Open GILD.High GILD.Low GILD.Close GILD.Volume GILD.Adjusted
#2012-01-03     41.46     41.99    41.35      41.86    19564000      20.46895
#2012-01-04     41.95     42.06    41.70      42.02    16236000      20.54719
#2012-01-05     42.04     42.97    42.00      42.52    18431800      20.79168
#2012-01-06     42.38     43.10    42.20      42.78    15542000      20.91882
#2012-01-09     42.49     42.99    42.35      42.73    16801200      20.89437
#2012-01-10     43.10     45.04    42.94      44.25    30110000      21.63763
```

This can be combined with an equivalent function `first()` to select a specific time span within the series.

Answer (score 1):

Your current argument to `[.xts` is just the character value `'start.date.char::end.date.char'` and would not be evaluated further, since R is not a macro language. Try instead to build the desired character value, which I believe is: `"2011-08-28::2016-08-26"`. So this succeeds:

```
GILD.5YTD<-GILD[paste(start.date.char, end.date.char, sep="::")]

str(GILD.5YTD)
#-------
An ‘xts’ object on 2011-08-29/2016-08-25 containing:
  Data: num [1:1257, 1:6] 39 39.7 40.2 39.8 39 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "GILD.Open" "GILD.High" "GILD.Low" "GILD.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-08-26 17:00:52"
```

So technically the `::` is not acting as an R operator, but is being parsed by the  `[.xts` function. Pkg:quantmod is built on top of the xts;package. The `"::"` function is really for package-directed function access for exported functions of installed packages.

Comment: This works as does what @alexis_las proposed as a comment to my question. You also clarified what's going on: **'stuff'** evaluates to **stuff** instead of assigned values. If you don't mind, what's a good reference for a newbie to be able to understand syntactical nuances  of  R, such as `[.xts` which sort of reads like  `xts` is a member of the operator `[`

Comment: If you want to learn about the notation, search on "generic functions in R". The `[` function is generic (as stated in first sentence of the Details section of the page brought up by `?'['`) and therefore has methods for items of particular classes. Objects of class "xts' (as was `GILD`) will get handled by the particular method that is appropriate for them and the actual function looked up by R's dispatch engine is named `[.xts`. Typing `?'[.xts'` at the console will bring up its help page

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your errors are that you are submitting the variables within a string which can not work. ( By the way you do not have to convert the date into `as.character` as in your example as pasting will do that for you). Using `paste0` like so will subset your data accordingly:

```
GILD.5YTD<-GILD[paste0(start.date.char,'::',end.date.char)]
```